# Ionic material app not running

Tags: android, git, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-material

I am trying to run the example ionic material app found here: https://github.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/

I have run the following commands:

```
$ ionic start myapp sidemenu
$ ionic platform add android
$ ionic build android
$ bower install ionic-material
```

running the app using $ ionic serve --lab works at this point and loads the same ionic sidemenu app.

I then replaced the www folder in the sample sidemenu app with the www folder from the ionic material git above.

Running the app using the serve command now doesn't show anything.

On removing the

```
, 'ionic-material', 'ionMdInput'
```

part of

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ionic-material', 'ionMdInput'])
```

at the top of app.js, runs the app but only shows the header bar.

What am I missing in order to run this ionic material sample app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Animation project running with ionic 1.5.5 in here:
https://github.com/nguyenthanhnhatcmu/Animation-for-ionic.git

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the www folder that ionic sets up by default with the same folder that comes with the material example.